# Android Studio - send data to mySql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to save some data from my android app to a mysql database on the server. The problem is that everything seems to be working perfectly, I get the message that my data has been sent successfully but my database doesn't receive anything.
I have the following files:

```
main.java
  // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        // Drawing the marker in the Google Maps
                        drawMarker(point);
                        // Drawing the circle
                        drawCircle(point);
                        //Add proximity alert
                        addProximAlert(point);

                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                        InputStream is = null;

                        // add values to the database
                        String name = "" + editText1.getText();
                        String description = "" + editText2.getText();
                        String latitude = "" + Double.toString(point.latitude);
                        String longitude = "" + Double.toString(point.longitude);

                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user","Someone"));

                        try {
                            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("XXXXX/data2.php");
                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            is = entity.getContent();
                            String msg = "Data has been sent successfully";
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_Tag");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            String msg2 = "Log_Tag";
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("Log_Tag", "IOException");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            String msg3 = "IOException";
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
```

and my php file

```
<?php

function createNewProduct() {
        $response = array();
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $description=$_POST['description'];
        $latitude=$_POST['latitude'];
        $longitude=$_POST['longitude'];
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        //$db = new DbConnect();

        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXX','XXXX');

        $query = "INSERT INTO pois(name,description,lat,longit,created_by) VALUES('$name','$description','$latitude','$longitude','$user')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($result) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "OK!";
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Failed!";
        }
       // echo json response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
createNewProduct();
?>
```

Any ideas/tips what can be the error?

EDIT:
Thank you all for your help! I found what the error was. It's a shame to say this but I was sending the wrong password in my php file. Everything works now.

Comment: What response do you get from the server?

Comment: First read response from InputStream `is` and see what it tells.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to test the PHP, use a tool to send the data to the php (like cURL for instance), and check that your server behaves as expected first.

Then, check that your android can correctly

```
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

on any server, and post the results.

Likely, the Android disabled the HttpCliente API (if Android 22+)

Comment: Its not a typing mistake. It's correct. The object is declared in this line: `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("XXXXX/data2.php");`

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake to misread that. What are the response on the request you have? Is it `OK!` or `Failed!`, and on your server, what is the request being received? From the wamp -> apache -> access log, you can see what request was received. Post it on your question

Answer (score 0):

I would try an echo response in php script to see if data actually comes to server. Then you can see if android does its part and you can isolate problem to either android or php code.
Also, I would suggest using Retrofit or volley for such GET or POST requests.